# comparing files using a do-while and for loops

Tags: java, loops

Let me start off by saying I'm open to a better way to handle this.  I've tried it a couple of different ways and I'm just not getting it.

The situation is that there are 2 folders of files.  Files in folder 1 are automatically downloaded from another source, daily.  What needs to happen is through a second program, the new file is processed and that end result then added to the second folder.

My approach is to use a couple of listarrays and compare the files in each list.  Then even if for some reason this program is down for a couple of days, it can still catch up with processing the files.  However, comparing the files is not working properly and I'm getting out of bounds errors.  The files from both lists are named with the date in Julian format, so that should make comparison possible.  Here's the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
    file = files.get(i);
    String fileDOY = file.substring(4, 7);
    int fileDOYint = Integer.parseInt(fileDOY);
}

boolean x = false;
ArrayList<String> dest = destin(name);
int j = 0;
do {
    String destination = dest.get(j);
    String dayDest = destination.substring(8, 10);
    int dayInt = Integer.parseInt(dayDest);

    if (dayInt == fileDOYint) {
        x = true;
    } 
    j++;
} while ((j < (dest.size() - 1)) || !x);

if (!x) {
    System.out.println("work " + file);
}
```

The output renders nothing except the error.  When I change the variable in the last if statement to process when true, it works up until a missing file then errors.  So, it seems to be working through the loops correctly, but something isn't hitting the last if statement.  The error indicates a problem on the first line after the "do" begins.

Comment: We will need to know or see what `destiny()` does. It seems as though it is returning an empty `ArrayList`

Comment: normally when you get errors in java, those errors have messages and/or stack traces.  They are useful for locating that place in the code where the error is coming from.

Comment: Why not just delete the file from folder1 after processing and saving to folder2.  Why keep file in 2 spots and compare in the first place?

Comment: @SamTebbs33 Dang, I missed adding that in.  Sorry about that.  It's a call to a method that fills the array.  It is a little more complicated as I needed to only add certain files to the array.

Comment: @SamIam Yes, as I stated it references back to the "String destination = dest.get(j);" line in the code.

Comment: @brso05 I am maintaining the data for future work.  I'm writing this for researchers who may have need for other parts of the files in the future.

Comment: I wish when people downgraded posts they had to specify why.  Was the question unclear? Was the answer it obvious? Was it asked multiple times before? I'm new to java and programming in general, so some feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your the `||` to `&&` in your `do while` condition

```
} while ((j < (dest.size() - 1)) && !x);
```

If you never find `fileDOYint`, your loop will continue and continue until you get an out of bounds exception, regardless of what `j` is.

Comment: Thank you, Sam I am.  You were exactly right.  I would have thought that getting either one condition or the other would have ended the loop, but my logic must be flawed.